Can the password for a user be customized during the initialization of a PXD deployment?
Could the password for the polardbx_root@'%' user be customized during the initialization of a PXD deployment in PolarDB?
I attempted to set the password using the following command:
SET PASSWORD FOR polardbx_root@'%' = PASSWORD('Deepwise123');

However, I encountered the following error:
ERROR 5107 (HY000): [18da9f3485402000][172.16.40.24:52684][polardbx]ERR-CODE: [PXC-5107][ERR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED] Can not modify polardbx_root since it is reserved for system

Is there a way to customize this password, or is it strictly reserved for system use?

